# Re-done rooms now much hotter

Tags: lighting, hvac

My daughters' rooms were re-done last fall - we tore out the closets, installed built-ins, replaced hollow doors with solid ones, did a bit of re-wiring for additional lights . . . During the spring we noticed that the rooms are now a lot hotter than the rest of the house.  And one room more than the other - by summer, this room was a good 10 degrees hotter than the rest of the house.

The guy who did the work says that the reason their rooms are now hotter is because they have more lights (they already had one overhead light, part of a fan - we added another light over their beds, and a vanity light, plus a lighted extending make-up mirror, all standard issue), and also because of the new solid doors.   In an attempt to compensate, I have turned out every light in the rooms and opened their doors wide, but it doesn't seem to help much.  And once the door closes which it inevitably does, it's definitely much hotter again.  We thought maybe some insulation in the attic got rolled back when the new overhead lights were installed, but everything seems to be in place.

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: I doubt it's a solid core door unless it weighs 50 pounds.  It's probably full of insulating honeycomb.

Comment: It is possible that an AC vent was covered by one of the built-ins and the room is now not getting as much air as it used to.

Comment: That wouldn't explain warmer in the winter.  Unless heat has separate registers.

Answer (score 8):

If it was worse insulation, the room would be colder in the winter and hotter in the summer.

If it's hot all the time, that's an energy burn inside the room.  What is the wattage of the various lightbulbs?

If they are not LED, it's time.  Boilerplate primer on LED buying: Think carefully about color temperature and CRI, 2700-3000 and 80+ are good choices for homes.  I just installed a ton of those and nobody can tell they aren't incandescent, except of course that they are 6 watts.  Buy GE, Cree, Philips or Ikea.  Don't buy Lights of America, Utilitech or Feit Electric, no matter how good the price is.  Choose wisely, you won't be replacing them for a very long time.

Do they own a home computer?  What kind? Did they change it recently?

Comment: I agree with the computer theory. A laptop especially tends to produce a lot of excess heat, and in a small room slightly better insulated that can make a big difference if there is no significant air flow. Consider adding a fan or a filtered duct near the ceiling into an interior wall.

Comment: My laptop has a 70W power supply, so it's not going to create more than 70W of heat even when fully loaded, most times it's well under that. 70W is less heat than a human body produces. Even a 17" gaming laptop comes with a 100 - 200W power adapter, and most of the time it will not be running near that limit. A gaming _desktop_, however, is another story, an overclocked desktop with multiple graphics cards can use 750W+ sustained power during gaming, and even at idle can use 200W or more.

Answer (score 2):

You have to have a gap under the door, about 1.5 inches, for the air to exit the room, otherwise the air will not enter. Perhaps your new door is longer, or your new carpet is blocking the exit.

Answer (score 1):

More lights definitely has an effect, particularly if the space is well insulated.

If you added carpet and carpet pad, that also increases the effective insulation.  A solid core door is also more insulating.

Maybe more people are spending more time in the room than before?  A human emits 100–300 watts of heat.

Comment: _"A human emits 300–700 watts of heat."_ - Not when at rest he doesn't. Ballpark figure for an adult at rest is about 100W ([source](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/116960/how-much-energy-in-form-of-heat-does-a-human-body-emit), [source](http://ergo.human.cornell.edu/studentdownloads/DEA3500notes/Thermal/thcondnotes.html)). 300W indicates heavy physical activity.

Comment: @marcelm: it can get even much lower like 50W, since the hotter it gets the less energy the body can dissipate.